# Hide bash script's content when displaying currently-running processes in Mac Terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have some bash script that writes the current timestamp to some file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
nohup & sh -c 'while [[ 1 ]];
do
    vardate=$(date +%d\-%m\-%Y\_%H.%M.%S);
    echo $vardate >> ~/test.txt;
    sleep 1;
done' &
```

When I run `ps -ef` in the list of all processes I can see it as:

```
...
501 32034     1   0 10:17PM ttys000    0:00.97 sh -c while [[ 1 ]];\012do\012    vardate=$(date +%d\-%m\-%Y\_%H.%M.%S);\012    echo $vardate >> ~/test.txt;\012    sleep 1;\012done
...
```

Is there any possibility to hide this PID at all or at least script's content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ps` is not displaying the script's content *per se*.  Rather, it is displaying the command line of a command that is running.  It just happens that that command was launched by your script and therefore appears within.

In fact, the script itself is pretty strange.  It's already a shell script, so what's the purpose of explicitly launching a new, separate shell in which to run the `while` loop (`sh -c`)?  I see no advantage over having the script execute the loop directly.

**Example:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while [[ 1 ]];
do
    vardate=$(date +%d\-%m\-%Y\_%H.%M.%S);
    echo $vardate >> ~/test.txt;
    sleep 1;
done
```

Or if it is indeed purposeful that the loop not be performed in the current shell, then why not use the `()` operator to run it in a subshell?

**Example**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
(
  while [[ 1 ]];
  do
    vardate=$(date +%d\-%m\-%Y\_%H.%M.%S);
    echo $vardate >> ~/test.txt;
    sleep 1;
  done
)
```

Both probably would avoid the `while` command appearing in your `ps` listing.

### In response to the question update:

The issue remains that if you use `sh -c` (or `bash -c`) to execute script text, then that script text is part of the command line, and can be displayed via `ps`.  The solution is the same too: feed the script to she shell via its *input* not via a command-line option.  You can combine that with `nohup` and background execution by use of a heredoc:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

nohup "$BASH" >> ~/test.txt 2>&1 <<'EOF' &
while [[ 1 ]]; do
  date +%d\-%m\-%Y\_%H.%M.%S
  sleep 1
done
EOF
```

That includes more changes from your original than are strictly necessary. Here's a summary, roughly in order of appearance:

- You don't need or want an `&` immediately following the `nohup` command.  I've omitted it.
- This version executes bash, not `sh`, and it does so via the automatic variable `$BASH`, which expands to the filename by which the current instance of bash was launched.
- The whole output of the nohup command (which launches `bash`) and also its stderr is redirected to the output file (`>> ~/test.txt 2>&1`).  This suppresses a diagnostic that is otherwise displayed for me, and it is more efficient than opening and closing the output file once per second, as the original does.
- The command's input (and indeed `nohup`'s) is redirected from a heredoc, without expansion by the current shell (`<<'EOF'` ... `EOF`).  This is the key component that prevents the script content from appearing in the process listing.  It is perhaps notable that the heredoc content does not actually start until the next line, so it doesn't include the `&`.  This is important, because the `&` terminates the command (and in fact the whole pipeline to which it belongs), so it cannot appear earlier.
- The `vardate` variable and `echo` command are eliminated in favor of just allowing the output of `date` to be printed directly.

Comment: thank you for such a nice and detailed answer. I forgot to add that I need to have this script running even after closing the terminal app, and therefore is has `nohup & sh .... done' &`. That is why it is a command in a separate shell.

Comment: That's uncool, @Claude.  It's poor manners to change the question in a substantive way after you've received an answer.

Comment: Ok, @Claude, I have written an addendum that addresses your revision to the question.